# The [checkpoint] tag brings in a lot of unrelated questions

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

I stumbled upon the [checkpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checkpoint) tag after googling for a software issue related to Check Point VPN. The tag description says it's about Check Point software, however most questions tagged with it are about checkpointing in relation to other programming problems. The top related tag is [tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow)

Should the tag description be updated to be more generic? I feel that the questions about the software related to Check Point would mostly be off topic anyways.

If so the tags [dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dump) & [memory-dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-dump) would also be related as checkpointing would usually involve dumping the memory.